# Cant install blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk with composer on laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, blockchain

The problem is 
I require blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk with composer on my laravel project and get these errors

```
Using version ^3.2 for blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for paragonie/random_compat (locked at v9.99.99) -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].
    - blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk v3.2.0 requires bitwasp/bitcoin v0.0.34.1 -> satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[v0.0.34.1].
    - blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk v3.2.1 requires bitwasp/bitcoin v0.0.34.1 -> satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[v0.0.34.1].
    - blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk v3.2.2 requires bitwasp/bitcoin v0.0.34.1 -> satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[v0.0.34.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install bitwasp/bitcoin v0.0.34.1
    - Installation request for blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk ^3.2 -> satisfiable by blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

COMPOSER.JSON require and require-dev contents

```
 "require": {
            "php": "^7.1.3",
            "bitwasp/bitcoin": "^0.0.34.1",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0",
            "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
            "laravel/socialite": "^3.1",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
            "paragonie/random_compat": "^2.0.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
            "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
        },
```

What can I do ? I tried everything , no point 
linux debian 8, php 7.2.9, laravel 5.7.5, thanks *

Comment: can you also add your composer.json to the question?

Comment: Ye s, I already added

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo some work here because it's a mess in dependencies where versions require symfony 3 and 4 at the same time (which will generate a conflict, that is not obvoius from the message you're getting right now). Same goes for deps for php 5.6 and 7.1 which are not fully compatible.

`blocktrail-sdk-php` already requires `bitwasp/bitcoin`, no need to add it in your own composer.json
https://github.com/blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk-php/blob/master/composer.json#L36

blocktrail-sdk-php also requires `99designs/http-signatures-guzzlehttp` 
which requires 
                "symfony/http-foundation": "~2.8|~3.0",

and then, you are requiring a newer http-foundation ("^4.1") in another package, specifically laravel-framework (check composer.lock)

I think your best option is to review what you actually want, review composer.json and create it again from scratch starting from the most important package.

Please start from the most important package, and match the versions to it starting from there. You'll have to review composer.json "require" node for every dependency package you need, and sometimes use some older package release (some of them are already made for symfony 4.X while some of your requirements can only handle 3.X). On github, you can easily switch to older revisions via dropdown on the top when you review composer.json to older version until the "require" matches your own dependency versions.

Please be aware you might have to prepare forks of the specific repos to make the adjustments.

If you're doing an update, remember to submit a PR with the package update, so programmers later don't have to fight the same thing :)